# default and only gravatar image in comments - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, gravatar

Is there possibility to make choosen gravatar image to be only image that will show up in comments? What I mean is when user, who have his own avatar image on email account, leave a comment then I don't want in that comment show up his image. In posted comments I want to be always one default image which I set it up in wp dashboard. How can I do that if it is possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your `comments.php` template, remove any reference to `get_avatar` and simply replace it with an image. That way anyone who comments will have the exact image.

**Update:**
Since your `comments.php` is calling the `wp_list_comments` function, you have to modify it and use a custom callback as [described here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments).

So replace `wp_list_comments(...);` with :

```
wp_list_comments( 'type=comment&callback=mytheme_comment' );
```

and in your `functions.php` file add:

```
function mytheme_comment($comment, $args, $depth) {
    if ( 'div' === $args['style'] ) {
        $tag       = 'div';
        $add_below = 'comment';
    } else {
        $tag       = 'li';
        $add_below = 'div-comment';
    }
    ?>
    <<?php echo $tag ?> <?php comment_class( empty( $args['has_children'] ) ? '' : 'parent' ) ?> id="comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
    <?php if ( 'div' != $args['style'] ) : ?>
        <div id="div-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>" class="comment-body">
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="comment-author vcard">
        <?php /* this is where avatar is displayed */ ?>

        <?php if ( $args['avatar_size'] != 0 ) echo get_avatar( $comment, $args['avatar_size'] ); ?>
        <?php /* remove the above and add something like this */ ?>
        <?php echo "<img src='YOUR-IMAGE-URL' class='user-avatar' />" ?>

        <?php printf( __( '<cite class="fn">%s</cite> <span class="says">says:</span>' ), get_comment_author_link() ); ?>
    </div>
    <?php if ( $comment->comment_approved == '0' ) : ?>
         <em class="comment-awaiting-moderation"><?php _e( 'Your comment is awaiting moderation.' ); ?></em>
          <br />
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="comment-meta commentmetadata"><a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ); ?>">
        <?php
        /* translators: 1: date, 2: time */
        printf( __('%1$s at %2$s'), get_comment_date(),  get_comment_time() ); ?></a><?php edit_comment_link( __( '(Edit)' ), '  ', '' );
        ?>
    </div>

    <?php comment_text(); ?>

    <div class="reply">
        <?php comment_reply_link( array_merge( $args, array( 'add_below' => $add_below, 'depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'] ) ) ); ?>
    </div>
    <?php if ( 'div' != $args['style'] ) : ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. There is no function like that in comments php. Only line wrapped in php tags where is used 'avatar' word is this:    wp_list_comments('type=comment&avatar_size=51&callback=obsequy_comment');